# Uneditable Div On HTML5

Tags: html, contenteditable

I just starting html see my following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>jklm</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: black;">
<div contenteditable="false" id="uiti" 
 style="width: 100%; background-color: whitesmoke;">
<img src="universal.bmp" alt="universal" height="80"
 width="60"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;kkk</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above created a div which can editable. You can write anything on it which I don’t want. I just want it as uneditable how to do?.

Comment: @sajmon_d, there are a div which contain a image if u click on such area of div it would allow to type or edit anything. suppose if you want to type a letter like "Mahesh" then you may allow it to type which I don't want it. I want to it would not allow anybody to type or edit an image location manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see minor problems in your code:

you need to close the **img** tag by adding a / before > ... like this:

```
<img src="universal.bmp" alt="universal" height="80" width="60"/>
```

also ... you don't need contenteditable="false". It's not editable by default.
If you want to make it editable do: `contenteditable="true"`

Answer (score 0):

A div is uneditable by default. You add that feature with the attribute **contenteditable** set to true or simply the attribute itself.

Remove it (or set it to false) & add the missing **/>** to image

```
<body style="background-color: black;">
    <div contenteditable="false" id="uiti" style="width: 100%; background-color: whitesmoke;">
     <img src="universal.bmp" alt="universal" height="80" width="60" /> 
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;kkk
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JuwVx/1/)